# Copy source to clipboard - can we make this user-friendlier?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I noticed that marking, copying and pasting code snippets in StackOverflow is a bit cumbersome - even if it is only one line of code, as in the following [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12332805/1016343) (there is a horizontal scrollbar - try to copy the entire line and you'll see what I mean):

[image]

How about adding a "Copy to clipboard" button, like it is done for example in [Microsoft's MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.exception.data(v=vs.110).aspx) and some other developer sites?

[image]

In this example, after clicking "allow access" once, the entire source code has been transferred to the clipboard and can now simply be pasted by using `Ctrl+V` into the source editor of your choice.

**N.B.** While this MSDN example seam to work in IE/Edge only, [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1042710/Solving-nonlinear-equation-systems-with-analytical) does it like this, which I've tested with IE and with Chrome successfully:

[image]

Please consider, if some of you don't need to copy the entire code, it is still useful for many others.

Comment: From my personal experience it is seldomly required to copy entire snippets, mostly just bits and pieces or only certain lines to point out mistakes and errors etc.

Comment: That link is IE/Edge only. See [this screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aIt9H.png) for what a Firefox user sees on that same page.

Comment: @Tim Castelijns: Consider that SO code snippets are useful to be used in **your** code, and copying snippets to point out errors is fine, but it is not the only usage you can think of.

Comment: It is strange for me to see so many downvotes. Other sites have this feature and it is useful, why not SO? Are you so conservative that you forget being innovative?

Comment: @Matt maybe people find it not innovative enough. It only takes a couple seconds at most to copy a snippet "manually" (provided it's not a wall of code that requires scrolling)

Comment: 1) Using Firefox CodeProject link just opens up a new window with the code in it. Nothing is actually copied to the clipboard. 2) How does the cost of implementing, testing, debugging cross-platform compatibility issues make this worth implementing? 3) How would you prioritize this feature request given the [2300 other](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+-status-completed) open feature requests?

Comment: @theB: Well, it surely isn't a "must have", it is just and idea that came into my mind when I visited other sites. And I agree it is only useful if you have a couple of lines of code, a 4-liner wouldn't benefit from it.

Comment: I think it's a well-intentioned idea, but the issue is really about "bloat" - I think SO favors a more spartan design/structure. this is motivated by issues of speed and performance. Are there add-ons you can use to accomplish this goal? maybe an extension?  Again, there were many similar ideas in the past (once I proposed "Canned Comments" os we can easily put common cmments, but it was deemed unnecessary bec. we have extensions to use )

Comment: I think Tim has a point too, if you only need to copy-paste code once every 2 days.. . then those extra 4 seconds to copy the code manually is not quite a big deal

Comment: @Coffee: If you know a nice extension I can use it would suit nicely - please let me know, which one does the job. Doesn't matter whether Chome, Firefox or IE as I need to have all 3 on my machine anyway.

Comment: N.B. I can see that there are also a couple of upvoters, so not all users think this idea is bad. And since the answer from rene shows there is also source available, it might be worth thinking about integrating it into SO some day ... hope dies last ...

Comment: Note, this feature was originally proposed about 5 years ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32625/shortcut-or-button-for-copying-posted-code-from-stack-overflow

Comment: Thanks for the link, and it received already **167 upvotes!**

Comment: Actually 190 upvotes, and 23 downvotes... So you've some catching-up to do on both fronts!

Comment: Wow, that is quite a lot :-D

Comment: I got 2 quite interesting answers so far, but unfortunately can't use them: Both are being blocked by firm policies and hence cannot be installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't test it my self but I believe the [Select Code Block Buttons Script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2553/select-code-block-buttons-script) over on [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/) might do the trick. The userscript is written by [H.B.](https://stackapps.com/users/6869/h-b).

Do notice that based on comments and answers not all script(s) seem to work for all browser/OS combinations so your mileage may vary.

Comment: May I ask a stupid question: How do I "inject" this script into Stackoverflow.com so it becomes available on each posted source?

Comment: That is not a stupid question. You'll need to install  TamperMonkey for Chrome or GreaseMonkey for FireFox. I'm not sure if there are similar plugins for IE, Opera or Safari. Those plugins enable you to paste the script in and then it will run at the pages it is designed for.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, that really brought me a step forward. I searched for TamperMonkey and GreaseMonkey at StackOverflow and found a useful question with answers I'd like to share: [Manually adding a Userscript to Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5258989/1016343)

Comment: Unfortunately this is being blocked by firm policies and cannot be installed.

Comment: @Matt I'm afraid I can only fix that if I buy your firm...

Comment: Right, Rene!  :-D  Well, I just wanted to remark in some enironments this can be blocked.

Comment: Why do not create a configurable option for people not to install the script but make the action button visible from a menu?

Comment: @sergzach maybe because that feature is not important enough to spend any dev-time on?

Comment: @rene May be. There must be huge amount of time to add a small button. Indeed I think that summary duration spending in discussions about it is more.

Comment: @sergzach not much [dev-time...](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/10/28/how-many-microsoft-employees-does-it-take-to-change-a-lightbulb/)

Comment: @rene Many smart guys, but many different opinions...

Comment: @sergzach yes, that is what makes MSO such a fun place to be at ...

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this is a useful request. When actively answering questions, it may save a good amount of time. 
Especially when using the touch-pad only, because it is uncomfortable to select large texts.

This problem is solved by the [Clipboardy Chrome extension](https://stackapps.com/questions/6753/clipboardy-chrome-extension-to-copy-posted-source-to-clipboard), listed on StackApps. 
A button is inserted near each source and in one click the text is copied to clipboard. Additionally buttons for selecting, collapsing text and a popup with recently copied items (usage history) are available.
It works on github.com & nmjs.com too.

[image]

[Install it from chrome store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clipboardy/gkafpbdjggkmmngaamlghmigadfaalhc).
[It's open source](https://github.com/panzerdp/clipboardy), so feel free to contribute or request new features.

Comment: Looks indeed quite useful, but unfortunately it dows not work for me: "Clipboardy (extension ID "....") is blocked by the administrator." This is due to firm policies.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for trying the extension and feedback. The problem you experience is related with the group policies the administrator applied. But the extension is [open source](https://github.com/panzerdp/clipboardy), so you can verify the code, make your own build and install it manually. Then  ask admins to allow the installation.