# Can line numbers for code and copy code to clipboard be appropriate in Stack Overflow questions?

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

Sometimes developers show the stack trace with code. For example:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Tucker Siegel/Desktop/Machines/Test.py", line 156, in <module>
    predictions = reg.predict(test)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 200, in predict
    return self._decision_function(X)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 183, in _decision_function
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 407, in check_array
    context))
ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 262)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
```

The interpreter shows lines which are invisible in a question.

And sometimes it's handsome to have a button to copy the code fast to try it.

Dear members, do you think it can be appropriate or not?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: @TZHX Is it not clear? I mean my code without line numbers and without a button to copy it to clipboard. Oh, it's not clear, thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252559/2564301

Comment: ..and duplicate of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308801/2564301. The problem with asking two questions in one is that I can only close as a dup of a single one.

Comment: @RadLexus smells too broad, huh?

Comment: Guys, you could put selecting code JavaScript into pages. It seems not too much place for a one small button.

Comment: @sergzach: the problem with line numbers, as pointed out in an answer in the linked question, is that your traceback refers to a "line 407". That means that some people are going to add *all* (at least) *407 lines* in their code. It's one of the reasons we generally ask for a [mcve]. (Wot no hot link on MSO?)

Comment: @RadLexus It's a line in the external file. To determine a current file we see to top of a stack - there is our source file. But OK, may be this idea is not so good. But what about fast code selection? Why don't make it as a button? The idea to install a custom script from APPS is strange at least. Should I install it to all my computers?

Answer (score 0):

One should create a [MCVE](/help/mcve) when writing a question. This is usually so small that it is trivial to find the correct line, especially when OP tells us exactly what the error is, and cuts out any lines after the error that obviously were not needed to recreate the problem.

Besides this, I don't think we should make it **harder** to handle code on this site. If you want to copy 2 lines, you should not have to jump through hoops to do so.